# Set Screen Title in ReactNative createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to set the Screen Title of the Navigated Screen by using `navigator`.  But it's not working/ changing and doesn't throw an exception either.

**Scenario**

I want to load some states from Redux and display nice Header Title in the Navigation Screen when the user clicks on the bottom Tab.

1. User clicks on second Tab in bottom navigation tab
2. Load state from Redux
3. Set Header Title

**Expected**

I want to set the following text to the Screen title

> headerTitle set in Screen

**Actual**

[image]

I declared my `BottomTabNavigator` as following:

```
import FilterScreen from '../screens/FilterScreen';
import ItemsListScreen2 from '../screens/ItemsListScreen copy';

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME = 'List';

export default function BottomTabNavigator({ navigation, route }) {

  // this code works
  navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: 'header Set in Navigator' });

  const [isFilterVisible, toggleFilter] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <BottomTab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME}
        tabBarOptions={{
          inactiveBackgroundColor: '#42a5f5',
          inactiveTintColor: '#ffffff'
        }}
      >
        <BottomTab.Screen
          name="List"
          component={ItemsListScreen}          
          options={{
            title: 'List',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-calendar" iconType="ion" />,
          }}
        />
        <BottomTab.Screen
          name="List2"
          headerMode="screen"
          component={ItemsListScreen2}
          screen
          options={{
            title: 'title List2',
            headerTitle: 'my header title',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-calendar" iconType="ion" />,
          }}
        />
    ....
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    </>
  );
}
```

In the above component, I could set the Screen Title by using `navigation.setOptions` and it works.

So, I tried to do the same operation to set the `headerTitle` in `List2` Screen.  But it doesn't have any effect to the screen header.  It only changes the label of the tab to "this is a title".

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const ItemsListScreen2 = ({ navigation }) => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerTitle: `headerTitle set in Screen`, // <-- no effect at the screen level
        title: "this is a title"
    });
return (
    <View>
        <Text>Screen 2</Text>
    </View>
);
}
```

I tried to do console.log to `navigation` object passed to the component and I can see it here:
[image]

Could you please help me to sort out this issue and suggest me how I could set the title from the screen?

Do I need to create a new function (Eg. `getHeaderTitle`), load the Redux state and set the title due to the route within BottomTabNavigation component?  I want to keep that component clean and I want to load the Redux States only when the user navigates to the screen.  I'd like to keep the screen specific codes in its own related screen.